# Shortcode with current page id

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've hit a wall with my little of knowledge of php.

Is there any way how to "put current page id" instead of particular id number in do_shortcode function in wordpress? Or is it matter of files inside of the plugin?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[plugin-review id="2"]'); ?>
```

I dont want to display content from page with id=2 on every page on my website when I put this code into a sidebar.

Thank you for a possible solution.

edit: I have just also found this function (there is more functions with same content) which might be maybe helpful?

`public function do_shortcode_ratings( $atts ) 
    {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'id'        => '',
            'template'  => '',
            'post'      => get_the_ID()
        ), $atts ) );`

```
    $shortcode = '[plugin-review id="'. $id .'" branch="ratings" post="'. $post .'" template="'. $template .'"]';

    return do_shortcode( $shortcode );

}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I am sorry i must have deleted before posting :/  <?php echo do_shortcode('[plugin-review id="2"]'); ?>

Comment: You cant try: ` $id = get_the_ID();'

Comment: That seems it doesnt work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current post/page ID is available via the global `$post` variable, i.e.

```
global $post;
$current_id = $post->ID;
```

Now you can use the `$current_id` in your shortcode :)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow, this one

```
global $post;
$current_id = $post->ID;
echo do_shortcode('[plugin-review id="'.$current_id.'"]');
```